# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation

Tags: java, security, exception, ssl, tls1.3

I'm pulling RSS data with an `HttpURLConnection` and get this error, but only on the server. Everything works fine on my laptop. So, the code is identical but I can't pin down the differences in environment.
Both are using the same VM arguments:
`-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.15.1/lib/security/cacerts" -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=<pwd> -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3`

I'm using openJdk v11_18. The keystore and password are good (I can list certs with the provided pwd)...

Comment: Add the debug flag `-Djavax.net.debug=all` and come back with a trace

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. stderr log prints out all certs and I see my root and subordinate cer entries. It also says `trustStore type is: pkcs12` and `keyStore provider is : <blank>`  Should there be a provider, and does it need to match SunJSSe from the original error:
`Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE...`?

Comment: An empty keyStore seems normal as you are not performing two-way SSL (I suppose). If not confidential, can you share the whole debug trace ?

Comment: I can't share the whole trace but did find this: `Inaccessible trust store: C:\Program Files\Java\openJdk11_18\lib\security\jssecacerts`
`trustStore is: C:\Program Files\Java\openJdk11_18\lib\security\cacerts`
I don't see any `jssecacerts` file (again, this works locally and I don't have the file locally either...).
Also: `SSLContextImpl.java:428|System property jdk.tls.client.cipherSuites is set to 'null'`.

Comment: OK you're using the default truststore and that might be fine. Interesting to see no cipher is used, at least one is necessary (for example TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA). Try adding that VM argument with one of the ciphers given in the [ciphersuites list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#ciphersuites). Maybe can you answer your own question.

Comment: It's working now. Thanks for your help, Eugene! 
This is soooo complicated... But, I got it working by creating my own keystore (which is not a trust store, I learned). Keystore certs allow others to trust you, while truststore allows you to trust others, I think.